# Como acessar uma variável dentro de uma função?

Tags: javascript

eu fiz um pequeno calendário onde ele cria os dias (30, 31, 28 - sem contar ano bisexto) de acordo com o mes selecionado.
ai eu decidi incrementar e adicionar os dias do mes anterior ai.
só que declarei a variavel no select.addeventlistener("change, (evento) =>{}

e fora tenho uma função que cria os dias do mês anterior
, mas pra ela funcionar preciso acessar umas variáveis que estão dentro do addeventlistener.

```
    const select = document.querySelector("select");
    
    select.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
        const mes = select.value;
        const dia = new Date("2022/"+mes+"/01");
        diaDaSemana = dia.getDay();
        qtdDiaMes = 31;
        const teste = (qtdDiaMes - (diaDaSemana-1)); //aqui tava só testando
        changer();
       


    });

      function changer(){
      for (let i = (qtdDiaMes-(diaDaSemana-1)); i <= qtdDiaMes; i++){
        const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
        const liCreator = document.createElement("li");
        liCreator.innerHTML = i;
        ul.appendChild(liCreator);
        console.log(qtdDiaMes);

  }
  criaCalendario();
}
```

a questão é. em addeventlistener vc nota que diaDaSemana e qtdDiaMes não tem var, let ou const

eu notei que se eu botar const, var ou let a função changer() não consegue acessar esses valores

em parte isso resolveria meu problema, mas gostaria de saber se isso é uma boa prática ou se tem outra forma de resolver isso.

agradeço desde já.

### --
https://github.com/imviniciussouza/calendar

no link acima tem a versão do calendário que já ta funcionando, esse codigo que postei aí fiz a parte pra ir testando.

Comment: Adicione parametros a função: `function changer(qtdDiaMes, diaDaSemana) { ...` e ao executar o charger chame-o assim: `const teste = (qtdDiaMes - (diaDaSemana-1)); //aqui tava só testando
        changer(qtdDiaMes, diaDaSemana);`. Recomendo que aprenda o básico de JS em: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions e https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope; Aqui mais tutoriais e docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso ocorre por causa do escopo das variáveis. Quando não declara a variável como let ou const ela vai ser considerada como var, e vai receber o escopo global, por isso você consegue acessar ela na função `changer`.

Não é boa prática deixar variáveis no escopo global dessa forma. Aconselho você a declarar as váriaveis `diaDaSemana` e `qtdDiaMes` foras do addEventListener e atribuir o valor delas dentro do addEventListener, dessa forma elas serão visíveis dentro da função `changer`

```
 const select = document.querySelector("select");
 let diaDaSemana;
 let qtdDiaMes;
    
    select.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
        const mes = select.value;
        const dia = new Date("2022/"+mes+"/01");
        diaDaSemana = dia.getDay();
        qtdDiaMes = 31;
        const teste = (qtdDiaMes - (diaDaSemana-1)); //aqui tava só testando
        changer();
    });

      function changer(){
      for (let i = (qtdDiaMes-(diaDaSemana-1)); i <= qtdDiaMes; i++){
        const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
        const liCreator = document.createElement("li");
        liCreator.innerHTML = i;
        ul.appendChild(liCreator);
        console.log(qtdDiaMes);

  }
  criaCalendario();
}
```

Recomendo também você a dar uma olhada nesse [artigo](https://medium.com/weyes/entendendo-o-uso-de-escopo-no-javascript-3669172ca5ba) para entender melhor sobre escopo de variáveis.